# Connect grouped points by line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to connect each blue point with its corresponding red point per group. However, I have trouble using `geom_segment`. Thx for help.

```
repl <- data.frame(title = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), diff = c(10.06, -1.89, 12.79, 10.06, -1.89, 12.79), id = c(1:6), acc= c(43, 50, 44, 43, 50, 44), variable= c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), value=c(43,50,44,53,48,56))


 ggplot(repl, aes(value, title, y=reorder(title, diff), group=variable, color=variable)) + 
     geom_point(size=2, shape=8)+
     geom_segment(aes(xend=value, x=value, y=title, yend=title), col='gray')
```

[image]

For each group there should be a line connecting the two points on the horizontal, how should I do that?

Comment: Do you want to connect lines within `variable` or between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do.

```
ggplot(repl, aes(x = value, y = reorder(title, diff),
                 group = title, color = variable)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2, shape = 8)+
    geom_line(col = 'gray')
```

**EDIT:**

What you want is to connect points by `title` while coloring them by `variable` hence the `group = title` and `color = variable` aesthetic.

Comment: Please add explanation how you solved the problem given OP's code.