# Connecting points by levels of a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I'm using in RStudio, and I have the code `ggplot(desktop_2015) + geom_point(aes(Month, CV, color = Day), size = 2.5)` in order to get a graph that I need.

I am plotting the variable `CV` by `Month`, and for each month there are 7 points along the vertical, each a different color representing a level of the variable `Day`.

What I am trying to do is connect the points for each day across the months, ie a line connecting each `Friday` point across the 12 months, and so on for each day of the week. I have attached images of what my dataset looks like in addition to the graph I currently have. TIA!

[image: graph]

Here's the dput output of my dataset:

```
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), Quarter = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
    "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = "factor"), 
    Device = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("D", "M", "T"), class = "factor"), Day = structure(c(4L, 
    2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
    7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 
    5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", 
    "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), 
    Clicks = c(1479, 1631, 1471, 1382, 1926, 1724, 1928, 1233, 
    1380, 1164, 1145, 1187, 1082, 1201, 1927, 1825, 1592, 1232, 
    1225, 1181, 1320, 1437, 1357, 1487, 1769, 1655, 1256, 1318, 
    1512, 1508, 1358, 1176, 1111, 1364, 1316, 1441, 2131, 1956, 
    1455, 1431, 1280, 1288, 2106, 2326, 2109, 2474, 2397, 2200, 
    1721, 2598, 2767, 2112, 2045, 1997, 1771, 2352, 2075, 2441, 
    2670, 2543, 1973, 1876, 1920, 2206, 2529, 2134, 2000, 2514, 
    2551, 2758, 3087, 3219, 2314, 2150, 1906, 1997, 2335, 1957, 
    2272, 2617, 2489, 2199, 1657, 1945), Conversions = c(67, 
    95, 110, 101, 88, 105, 114, 89, 92, 79, 67, 72, 96, 76, 139, 
    125, 89, 47, 63, 73, 78, 97, 127, 69, 96, 61, 50, 90, 83, 
    91, 85, 56, 117, 66, 94, 48, 86, 71, 63, 53, 46, 56, 67, 
    75, 64, 64, 63, 55, 59, 74, 71, 62, 59, 57, 40, 71, 69, 84, 
    80, 101, 61, 76, 56, 93, 69, 50, 47, 73, 67, 98, 108, 127, 
    59, 67, 68, 88, 77, 60, 69, 82, 72, 55, 44, 54), CV = c(9089.21, 
    7811.24, 13201.19, 11394.8, 12631.15, 12389.61, 11742.6, 
    10265.62, 12449.76, 9329.68, 8255.08, 9002.71, 13173.41, 
    6235.05, 15480.72, 17940.65, 13667.19, 5766.98, 7583.03, 
    6817.59, 6412.43, 10441.66, 23018.46, 9243.69, 10521.5, 15117.06, 
    5791.93, 7783.52, 8156.31, 9996.18, 12973.64, 6329.24, 20080.53, 
    6289.64, 10891.91, 7176.93, 10281.64, 10292.1, 10077.85, 
    9299.89, 5979.86, 6888.64, 6799.56, 13162.34, 10267.85, 10599.65, 
    8868.4, 7285.48, 8393, 9930.09, 10857.6, 12568.96, 9998.93, 
    8465.09, 6733.55, 11107.85, 10919.87, 12933.21, 14653.55, 
    22648.43, 13272.86, 15214.25, 9733.4, 18128.61, 12915.65, 
    10267.21, 9804.48, 11928.58, 14135.84, 19990.35, 15482.84, 
    20116.57, 12705.79, 12891.93, 11266.43, 16632.9, 11890.34, 
    9290.67, 11417.62, 18980.21, 11025.63, 7806.93, 7246.12, 
    7737.87), `Conv. rate` = c(0.0453, 0.0582, 0.0748, 0.0731, 
    0.0457, 0.0609, 0.0591, 0.0722, 0.0667, 0.0679, 0.0585, 0.0607, 
    0.0887, 0.0633, 0.0721, 0.0685, 0.0559, 0.0381, 0.0514, 0.0618, 
    0.0591, 0.0675, 0.0936, 0.0464, 0.0543, 0.0369, 0.0398, 0.0683, 
    0.0549, 0.0603, 0.0626, 0.0476, 0.1053, 0.0484, 0.0714, 0.0333, 
    0.0404, 0.0363, 0.0433, 0.037, 0.0359, 0.0435, 0.0318, 0.0322, 
    0.0303, 0.0259, 0.0263, 0.025, 0.0343, 0.0285, 0.0257, 0.0294, 
    0.0289, 0.0285, 0.0226, 0.0302, 0.0333, 0.0344, 0.03, 0.0397, 
    0.0309, 0.0405, 0.0292, 0.0422, 0.0273, 0.0234, 0.0235, 0.029, 
    0.0263, 0.0355, 0.035, 0.0395, 0.0255, 0.0312, 0.0357, 0.0441, 
    0.033, 0.0307, 0.0304, 0.0313, 0.0289, 0.025, 0.0266, 0.0278
    ), `CV/Click` = c(6.15, 4.79, 8.97, 8.25, 6.56, 7.19, 6.09, 
    8.33, 9.02, 8.02, 7.21, 7.58, 12.18, 5.19, 8.03, 9.83, 8.58, 
    4.68, 6.19, 5.77, 4.86, 7.27, 16.96, 6.22, 5.95, 9.13, 4.61, 
    5.91, 5.39, 6.63, 9.55, 5.38, 18.07, 4.61, 8.28, 4.98, 4.82, 
    5.26, 6.93, 6.5, 4.67, 5.35, 3.23, 5.66, 4.87, 4.28, 3.7, 
    3.31, 4.88, 3.82, 3.92, 5.95, 4.89, 4.24, 3.8, 4.72, 5.26, 
    5.3, 5.49, 8.91, 6.73, 8.11, 5.07, 8.22, 5.11, 4.81, 4.9, 
    4.74, 5.54, 7.25, 5.02, 6.25, 5.49, 6, 5.91, 8.33, 5.09, 
    4.75, 5.03, 7.25, 4.43, 3.55, 4.37, 3.98), Impressions = c(86045, 
    89512, 81503, 81356, 101254, 95972, 100790, 73492, 81709, 
    71678, 67884, 68429, 61978, 69537, 99440, 99735, 95689, 71773, 
    71414, 65363, 69422, 77640, 76419, 81980, 97540, 90953, 67780, 
    68886, 81265, 79079, 70807, 65774, 59298, 72504, 71965, 92817, 
    132684, 120931, 93380, 89791, 82604, 79651, 121598, 141042, 
    132627, 167622, 146056, 133295, 103366, 151998, 170043, 142676, 
    126557, 121835, 121060, 139303, 113975, 127019, 151171, 140981, 
    110230, 108527, 106218, 123960, 136940, 123136, 120845, 145673, 
    136340, 144527, 185146, 210133, 157902, 135150, 124981, 132650, 
    136682, 127909, 156160, 219576, 187283, 143617, 107303, 128768
    ), Cost = c(1376.23, 1799.57, 1646.93, 1631.22, 2088.67, 
    1869.83, 1779.56, 1152.91, 1643.25, 1281.38, 1368.1, 1299.16, 
    1184.99, 1183.82, 1690.38, 2065.43, 1737.26, 1351.85, 1432.21, 
    1395.46, 1192.53, 1385.88, 1548.41, 1754.96, 2148.9, 2061.52, 
    1481.82, 1400.12, 1595.65, 1808.54, 1643.06, 1417.31, 1343.52, 
    1794.69, 1317.59, 1436.56, 2344.1, 2124.41, 1602.12, 1449.17, 
    1417.73, 1337.39, 1773.49, 2018.75, 1813.7, 2181.56, 2069.48, 
    1938.4, 1528.46, 1907.15, 2163.95, 1645.47, 1620.2, 1552.78, 
    1326.68, 1749.51, 1466.75, 1851.91, 1997.14, 1909.85, 1506.9, 
    1391.86, 1420.54, 1671.03, 1948.89, 1657.35, 1577.12, 1888.6, 
    1934.2, 2055.61, 2357.6, 2426.16, 1730.51, 1652.82, 1464.03, 
    1550.73, 1736.98, 1364.01, 1625.97, 1835.38, 1714.8, 1584.55, 
    1109.67, 1340.77)), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 
19L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 31L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 44L, 47L, 51L, 52L, 57L, 
58L, 63L, 64L, 69L, 72L, 74L, 78L, 81L, 82L, 85L, 89L, 92L, 95L, 
97L, 100L, 105L, 107L, 111L, 113L, 116L, 119L, 121L, 124L, 127L, 
130L, 135L, 136L, 141L, 142L, 147L, 149L, 152L, 154L, 158L, 161L, 
163L, 167L, 171L, 174L, 177L, 178L, 181L, 185L, 188L, 191L, 194L, 
198L, 201L, 202L, 207L, 208L, 211L, 215L, 218L, 221L, 225L, 228L, 
230L, 232L, 236L, 238L, 242L, 246L, 247L, 250L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image  No one wants to type it all in. Instead,  used `dput` to make a text version of your data, put that in your question so that we can cut and paste your data.  You might want to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! is it best to just copy and paste the output of the ```dput``` function into my question? (sorry I am new to stackflow and also just not an expert at code)

Comment: Trying adding `group=Day` to the aes definition.

Comment: Have you checked `lemon::geom_pointpath()`? It sounds like it might help you

Comment: Yes.   Pleas copy and paste output of dput into your question unless your data is very large.

Comment: Adding ```group = Day``` into the aes def of ```geom_line``` worked perfectly! thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect grouped points by line in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326600/connect-grouped-points-by-line-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @Tjebo that worked when I added ```group = Day``` into ```geom_line(aes(Month, CV, group = Day, color = Day))```, but not into the aes defintion of ```geom_point```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide both `group` and `color` in your `aes`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = CV, color = Day, group = Day))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

[image]